# Python zip For loop improvement

Tags: python

```
    for d, e, f, g, h, j, k, l, m, n in zip(dis['D'], dis['E'], dis['F'],
                                            dis['G'], dis['H'], dis['J'],
                                            dis['K'], dis['L'], dis['M'],
                                            dis['N']):
        d.number_format = "$#,##0_);($#,##0)"
        e.number_format = "$#,##0_);($#,##0)"
        f.number_format = "$#,##0_);($#,##0)"
        g.number_format = "$#,##0_);($#,##0)"
        h.number_format = "$#,##0_);($#,##0)"
        j.number_format = "$#,##0_);($#,##0)"
        k.number_format = "$#,##0_);($#,##0)"
        l.number_format = "$#,##0_);($#,##0)"
        m.number_format = "$#,##0_);($#,##0)"
        n.number_format = "$#,##0_);($#,##0)"
```

Is there any way to do this more pythonic way? dis[''] are columns of a excel worksheet so I need to apply all formats individually, I am using openpyxl for this

Comment: ```for l in 'DEFGHJKLMN': for a in dis[l]: a.number_format = 'whatever'```

Comment: question is not related to `pylint` nor to `pep8` tags were removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for currentKey in "DEFGHIJKLMN":
    for cell in dis[currentKey]:
        cell.number_format = "$#,##0_);($#,##0)"
```

This was the best way I could find

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this would help

```py
keys = ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N']
for currentKey in keys:
    for cell in dis[currentKey]:
        cell.number_format = "$#,##0_);($#,##0)"
```